# Don't fill minted environments in AUCTex

Tags: latex, auctex

When running `M-x LaTeX-fill-environment` I don't want code in a `minted` environments to be formatted. I tried adding `minted` to `LaTeX-fill-excluded-macros` but that didn't have any effect on the filling. Any ideas on how to exclude certain environments from the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LaTeX-fill-excluded-macros` should contain name of macros for whose arguments filling should be disabled, e.g. `\macro{do not fill this}`.

For your specific case, I suggest you use the support file for `minted.sty` coming with AUCTeX and activate it by putting this in your init file:

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

Restart Emacs and open your .tex file again.  If you have an up to date AUCTeX, you'll get access to all features provided by `minted.sty` within Emacs.